# Sort rows of numpy matrix efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 2d array of real numbers, for example

```
A=
np.array(
[[0.1, 0.01, 0.4, 0.9], 
[0.0005, -0.2, -0.1, 0.6], 
[-0.3, -0.5, 0.2, 0.9]])
```

and a vector of indices of the same size of `A.shape[1]`: `idx=[5, 2, 3, 9]`

for every row of A, I need to sort the entries from high to low, and provide the corresponding elements from idx. For example, in the case above the answer should be:

```
np.array([[9, 3, 5, 2], [9, 5, 3, 2], [9, 3, 5, 2]])
```

There can be millions of row in A. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of a `sort by column` question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.argsort()` to get the indices of your array in a sorted mode and reverse it to get the indices of decreasing mode, then use a simple indexing to get your expected output:

```
>>> A.argsort()
array([[1, 0, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 0, 3],
       [1, 0, 2, 3]])
>>> idx=np.array([5, 2, 3, 9])

>>> indices = A.argsort()[:,::-1]
>>> 
>>> idx[indices]
array([[9, 3, 5, 2],
       [9, 5, 3, 2],
       [9, 3, 5, 2]])
```